# Convertion of tabular data to JSON in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am unable to figure out how to convert tabular data to JSON format and store it in another table in Redshift. For example, I have a `"DEMO"` table with four columns: `pid,stid,item_id,trans_id`.

For each combination of `pid,stid,item_id` there exist many `trans_id`s.

```
pid  stid  item_id  trans_id :

1 , AB  , P1 , T1  
1 , AB  , P1 , T2  
1 , AB  , P1 , T3     
1 , AB  , P1 , T4   
2 , ABC , P2 , T5  
2 , ABC , P2 , T6  
2 , ABC , P2 , T7  
2 , ABC , P2 , T8
```

I want to store this data in another table called `"SAMPLE"` as:

```
pid  stid  item_id      trans_id

1 , AB  , P1 , {"key1":T1, "key2":"T2" "key2":"T3" "key2":"T4"}    
2 , ABC , P2 , {"key1":T5, "key2":"T6" "key2":"T7" "key2":"T8"}
```

I am unable to figure out how to load the data from `"DEMO"` to `"SAMPLE"` in JSON format only for column `"trans_id"` using a SQL query in Redshift. I don't want to use any intermediate files.

Answer (score 6):

There is `LISTAGG` aggregate function that allows you to concatenate text values within groups. It allows the effective construction of JSON objects:

```
SELECT
 pid
,stid
,item_id
,'{'||listagg(
    '"key'||row_number::varchar||'":'||trans_id::varchar
    ,',') within group (order by row_number)
 ||'}'
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by pid,stid,item_id order by trans_id)
    FROM "DEMO"
)
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

As a side note, in this particular case an array of transaction IDs might work better, you'll be able to request the element of a specific order easily without using `keyN` key:

```
WITH tran_arrays as (
    SELECT
     pid
    ,stid
    ,item_id
    ,listagg(trans_id::varchar,',') within group (order by trans_id) as tran_array
    FROM "DEMO"
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
SELECT *
,split_part(tran_array,',',1) as first_element
FROM tran_arrays;
```

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to the existing Answer however slightly different.  This example is also run out of an Oracle Database.  I put the work into it and felt like sharing in case it may help someone else out.

```
/* Oracle Example */
WITH demo_data AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS pid, 'AB' AS stid, 'P1' AS item_id, 'T1' AS trans_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS pid, 'AB' AS stid, 'P1' AS item_id, 'T2' AS trans_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS pid, 'AB' AS stid, 'P1' AS item_id, 'T3' AS trans_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS pid, 'AB' AS stid, 'P1' AS item_id, 'T4' AS trans_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS pid, 'ABC' AS stid, 'P2' AS item_id, 'T5' AS trans_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS pid, 'ABC' AS stid, 'P2' AS item_id, 'T6' AS trans_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS pid, 'ABC' AS stid, 'P2' AS item_id, 'T7' AS trans_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS pid, 'ABC' AS stid, 'P2' AS item_id, 'T8' AS trans_id FROM dual
)
, transformData AS
(
SELECT pid, stid, item_id, trans_id, rownum AS keyNum FROM demo_data
)

SELECT pid, stid, item_id
  , '{'||
    LISTAGG(CHR(34)||'key'||keynum||CHR(34)||':'||CHR(34)||trans_id||CHR(34), ' ')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pid)
    ||'}' AS trans_id

FROM transformData
GROUP BY pid, stid, item_id
;
```

Output will look like this:

[image]